# Гиперссылки в гугл таблицы неправильно вставляются

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

###### Проблемный участок:

```python
nickname_column_index = headers.index("Никнейм")
hyperlink_formula = f'=HYPERLINK("{profile_url}";"{row_data[nickname_column_index]}")'
row_data[nickname_column_index] = hyperlink_formula

worksheet.append_row(row_data)
```

Должно выдавать примерно вот это: `=HYPERLINK("https://osudroid.moe/profile.php?uid=199199","AWildGiraffe")`
Однако выдает `'=HYPERLINK("https://osudroid.moe/profile.php?uid=199199","AWildGiraffe")`
Нюанс в кавычке которая стоит первым символом[image: Скриншот показывающий проблему с кавычкой вместо формулы]

###### Полный код:

```pytnon
def append_data_to_google_sheet(gc, user_info, profile_url, start_time, end_time, headers):
    uid = user_info["UID"]
    country = user_info["Местоположение"]
    if not country:
        country = "Unknown"

# Открываем Google Sheets файл
spreadsheet = gc.open("osudroiddata")  # Замените на фактическое имя вашего Google Sheets файла

# Проверяем, существует ли лист для состояния, и создаем его, если не существует
state_sheet_name = "Состояние"
try:
    state_worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(state_sheet_name)
except gspread.exceptions.WorksheetNotFound:
    state_worksheet = spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title=state_sheet_name, rows="5000", cols="5")  # Увеличиваем количество столбцов на 2
    state_worksheet.append_row(["UID", "Техническое состояние ПК (CPU)", "Техническое состояние ПК (Memory)", "Время запроса", "Время обработки"])

# Получаем техническое состояние ПК
cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent()  # Загрузка ЦПУ в процентах
memory_usage = psutil.virtual_memory().percent  # Загрузка памяти в процентах

# Записываем состояние в лист состояния
state_worksheet.append_row([uid, f"{cpu_usage}%", f"{memory_usage}%", start_time, end_time])

# Открываем лист для страны, если он существует, и создаем его, если не существует
try:
    worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(country)
except gspread.exceptions.WorksheetNotFound:
    worksheet = spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title=country, rows="1", cols="14")  # Увеличиваем количество столбцов на 3 # Add additional headers
    worksheet.append_row(headers)

row_data = [user_info[key] for key in user_info.keys()]

# Insert the hyperlink formula for the nickname using the profile_url
nickname_column_index = headers.index("Никнейм")
hyperlink_formula = f'=HYPERLINK("{profile_url}";"{row_data[nickname_column_index]}")'
row_data[nickname_column_index] = hyperlink_formula

worksheet.append_row(row_data)

# Выводим информацию о процессе
print(f"Обработан UID {uid}")
```

Comment: я не уверен, но, по-моему, запись в ячейку нужно делать по типу `sheet.update_acell('A1','=HYPERLINK("...","...")')`